# Pass parameter from external js to react prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to convert an in-app webpage to React. The app webview automatically calls a Javascript function to pass an access token to the webpage. So is it possible to use the same existing function to pass the token variable and store it as a React prop?

HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script>
    function setToken(token){
    //set token to App token prop
  }
</script>
```

JS

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: "",
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.token}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wzovs2gy/

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a callback function, so it will be given another function to call when it has a result (meaning it would be passed a function from within React that would then update the state/props. If you're looking to do this with a minimal number of changes, I would suggest that you have the function store the token in a variable, and then later query this variable in React.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible - or at least impractical - to access React component instance outside React application. This should be done in opposite way, the component should expose global function:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: "",
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.setToken = token => {
      this.setState({ token });
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

`setToken` shouldn't be called before React component initialization. Depending on where `setToken` is called, it may be beneficial to wrap the code that uses it with React application instead and avoid using globals.

Comment: the setToken is called by the app once the webpage has finished loading. I just need a way to define the setToken function which can be called by the app whether its inside or outside React.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the fiddle:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: "test",
    }
  }
componentDidMount(){    
    setToken(this.state.token);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.token}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wzovs2gy/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do the reverse. The app calls the setToken function on the webpage once the webpage has finished loading.

Comment: Means setToken value will set on the state??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys, managed to figure out a solution (while not elegant does the job). I declared the ReactDom.Render() as a variable which allows me to reference the function within the React Parent in the Vanilla JS.

JS

```
var ReactDom = ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

HTML

```
function setToken(token){
    ReactDom.setNewToken(token);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wzovs2gy/2